# How to detect whether "I'm on arXiv.org"?

Tags: conditionals, documentclass-writing, online, class-options

I write a class. I'm interested in having a different page headers (and eventually make some other small differences) based on whether the class is used on the site [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org/) or not. Minimal example follows:

**myclass.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/02/27]

\LoadClass{article}
\date{}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

%\ifABC
\fancyhead[C]{arXiv version}
%\fi

\pagestyle{fancy}
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\endinput
```

**testarticle.tex**

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\title{Just an Article}
\author{Me the First}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

In the file `myclass.cls`, the if conditional (disabled in MWE) should detect whether "arXiv or not". Since the class file will be used by many people I don't know, solution as bullet-proof as possible is welcomed, as well as just ideas that might need further development to work. My first idea was to detect at the beginning whether the package `hyperref` is loaded before the classfile is processed (since it's always loaded on arXiv), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you can use to detect what system things are being run on _unless_ you know that there is some testable information set by the platform. Presumably that requires insight into the arXiv set up, which we can't really offer.

Comment: `\ifx\tikzversion\reallyreallyoutdated \arxivtrue \else \arxivfalse \fi`

Comment: @JosephWright arXiv does _crazy things_ to the articles: disregards `a4paper` option sometimes, activates `hyperref` by default, adds the arXiv stamp on the first page etc. Some of them _must_ be possible to detect. I'll look into it during the weekend if I don't get an answer here inbetween.

Comment: The [arXiv](http://arXiv.org) uses [AutoTeX](http://search.cpan.org/~tschwand/TeX-AutoTeX-v0.906.0/lib/TeX/AutoTeX.pm) to process the files.  You might check the documentation/source to see if it defines any macros you can use to check.

Comment: @tohecz How do you test?  Apart from days where I submit articles (with a frequency counted in tens of nanohertz), I don't see when I could.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch no-how, I mean, I don't test it in the end, I've dropped this feature until I find time to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an explicit flag being set by the 'host' platform, there is no general way of detecting that a `.tex` file is being processed by a particular publisher's system. Thus without knowledge of the arXiv system, and probably contacts, there is no way to achieve this detection.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar question on academia.se today and was pointed to this question. I posted a hack [there](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67998/how-to-detect-whether-the-paper-is-being-compiled-inside-arxiv) which can work for your situation also.

Basically make a separate empty file called `myclass.dont.upload.to.arxiv` then use `IfFileExists` function in latex to test whether this file is present or not and take action accordingly. When you have to upload the paper to arxiv then don't upload this file. Problem Solved.

Comment: No, you discuss a situation in which you are the author of the paper. But I'm not. I'm the author of the LaTeX class. Whence, your solution can not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as possible we like answers to be self-contained, and in particular not rely on links, as thi makes them easier to read and we don't have to worry about the links vanishing in the future.